# Java Code Working On An Online Compiler But Not In Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am studying  Computer Science at GCSE and I've came across a problem. Initially, our teacher cannot help me due to the AQA Guidelines but I am allowed to ask on forums etc. So here's the problem:

```
class Price {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int day;
        double price = 0.00;



    System.out.print("How many days would you like to reserve the game?:  ");
    day = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (day >= 4 && day <= 5) {
        price = 5.55;

        System.out.print("You have chosen to reserve the game for " + day + " days! ");

        System.out.println("Please pay £" + price + ". " + " Enjoy your game!");
        }

    if (day == 3) {
        price = 3.45;

        System.out.print("You have chosen to reserve the game for " + day + " days! ");

        System.out.println("Please pay £" + price + ". " + " Enjoy your game!");
        }

    if (day >= 1 && day <= 2) {
        price = 2.75;

        System.out.print("You have chosen to reserve the game for " + day + " days! ");

        System.out.println("Please pay £" + price + ". " + " Enjoy your game!");

    }
    if (day > 5 || day <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number - Days of Reservation Are 1-5 Only. Please Try Again.");
    }

    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

My problem is that this code works on Online Compilers such as www.browxy.com with no worries yet Eclipse reads the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:
>
> Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
>
> Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at Price.main(Price.java:3)"

Has anyone got a  solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you import `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: Your java version might not be supporting Scanner class. What is your Java version?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an `import` statement for the `Scanner` class before the class definition:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Most likely the classes from the `java.util` package are imported by default in the online IDE.

Also, Eclipse (and most of the other IDEs, actually) support a keyboard shortcut, which adds the import statements for you. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

you should `import` `Scanner` class in java to have capability of compiler to accept user input on runtime add below line on top of your class declaration and the problem will get solved

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Note: you can also use `compile time arguments` like for example `args[]` if `scanner` class is not present in your `JDK` version

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` is present from java 1.5.
Check if you jdk is a version prior to 1.5.
If your jdk version is 1.5 or later you need to add the import `java.util.Scanner` at the top of the file.